# How can I update the correct size of a RelativeLayout view, after scaling it down?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a class based on [TwoDScrollView](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/CustomScrollViews/blob/master/library/src/com/doomonafireball/customscrollviews/widget/TwoDScrollView.java), which extends FrameLayout. It has a single child view of a class which extends RelativeLayout. I've added pinch-zoom functionality to the parent FrameLayout, which then changes the scale of the child RelativeLayout:

```
child().setScaleX(scale);
child().setScaleY(scale);
```

Note: it only lets you zoom out (scale > 1), not in.

The parent FrameLayout should also automatically shrink down with the child, but it keeps exactly the same size as before zooming out. Not surprising, because when I check the child's width with `getMeasuredWidth()`, it's always 2098, both before and after scaling.

Why are the width and height measurements of the child view not affected by it's scaling? how can I resolve it correctly for the parent to also reduce its size accordingly?

Comment: I've found some possible solutions, but would be interesting to hear if there are more robust approaches to this. My solution is to override onMeasure() in the child, to take its scale into account. Problem is that getRight() and getBottom(), which are used in the scrolling to detect maximum scrolling range, also ignore scale completely, and are final, so can't be overriden. Hence, I had to add the scale on every call to getRight() and getBottom(), making it ugly and inconsistent. So, while this works for me now, would be interesting to hear better ideas.

Comment: to clarify: getRight() and getBottom() are (I think) calling onMeasure. In my specific case, I had to leave onMeasure unaltered, but needed getRight and getBottom to also consider scale, leading to my solution of applying scale to all of their calls on the TwoDScrollView.